# Is it possible to create custom Swift KeyEncodingStrategy for enums only?

Tags: swift, enums, jsonencoder

Update June 20, 2019: Thanks to @rudedog, I arrived at a working solution. I've appended implementation below my original post...

---

#### Note that I am NOT looking for "use private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey" in your struct/enum declaration.

I have a situation in which a service I call requires upper snake_case (`UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`) for all enumerations.

Given the following `struct`:

```swift
public struct Request: Encodable {
    public let foo: Bool?
    public let barId: BarIdType
    
    public enum BarIdType: String, Encodable {
        case test
        case testGroup
    }
}
```

All enums in any request should be converted to UPPER_SNAKE_CASE.

For example, `let request = Request(foo: true, barId: testGroup)` should end up looking like the following when sent:

```swift
{
    "foo": true,
    "barId": "TEST_GROUP"
}
```

I would like to provide a custom `JSONEncoder.KeyEncodingStrategy` that would ONLY apply to `enum` types.

Creating a custom strategy seems straightforward, at least according to Apple's [JSONEncoder.KeyEncodingStrategy.custom(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/keyencodingstrategy/custom) documentation.

Here's what I have so far:

```swift
public struct AnyCodingKey : CodingKey {

    public var stringValue: String
    public var intValue: Int?

    public init(_ base: CodingKey) {
        self.init(stringValue: base.stringValue, intValue: base.intValue)
    }

    public init(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    public init(intValue: Int) {
        self.stringValue = "\(intValue)"
        self.intValue = intValue
    }

    public init(stringValue: String, intValue: Int?) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
        self.intValue = intValue
    }
}

extension JSONEncoder.KeyEncodingStrategy {

    static var convertToUpperSnakeCase: JSONEncoder.KeyEncodingStrategy {
        return .custom { keys in // codingKeys is [CodingKey]
            // keys = Enum ???

            var key = AnyCodingKey(keys.last!)
            // key = Enum ???

            key.stringValue = key.stringValue.toUpperSnakeCase // toUpperSnakeCase is a String extension
            return key
        }
    }
}
```

I'm stuck trying to determine whether [CodingKey] represents an enum, or whether the individual CodingKey represents an enum, and should therefor become UPPER_SNAKE_CASE.

I know this sounds pointless, since I can simply supply hardcoded CodingKeys, but we have a lot of service calls, all requiring the same handling of enum cases. It would be simpler to just specify a custom KeyEncodingStrategy for the encoder.

What would be ideal is to apply `JSONEncoder.KeyEncodingStrategy.convertToSnakeCase` in the custom strategy and then just return the uppercased value. But again, only if the value represents an enum case.

Any thoughts?

---

## Here is the code I arrived at that solved my problem, with help from @rudedog:

```swift
import Foundation

public protocol UpperSnakeCaseRepresentable: Encodable {
    var upperSnakeCaseValue: String { get }
}

extension UpperSnakeCaseRepresentable where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {
    var upperSnakeCaseValue: String {
        return _upperSnakeCaseValue(rawValue)
    }
}

extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
    mutating func encode(_ value: UpperSnakeCaseRepresentable, forKey key: KeyedEncodingContainer<K>.Key) throws {
        try encode(value.upperSnakeCaseValue, forKey: key)
    }
}

// The following is copied verbatim from https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift
// Copyright (c) 2014 - 2017 Apple Inc. and the Swift project authors
// Licensed under Apache License v2.0 with Runtime Library Exception
// The only change is to call uppercased() on the encoded value as part of the return.
fileprivate func _upperSnakeCaseValue(_ stringKey: String) -> String {
    guard !stringKey.isEmpty else { return stringKey }

    var words : [Range<String.Index>] = []
    // The general idea of this algorithm is to split words on transition from lower to upper case, then on transition of >1 upper case characters to lowercase
    //
    // myProperty -> my_property
    // myURLProperty -> my_url_property
    //
    // We assume, per Swift naming conventions, that the first character of the key is lowercase.
    var wordStart = stringKey.startIndex
    var searchRange = stringKey.index(after: wordStart)..<stringKey.endIndex

    // Find next uppercase character
    while let upperCaseRange = stringKey.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters, options: [], range: searchRange) {
        let untilUpperCase = wordStart..<upperCaseRange.lowerBound
        words.append(untilUpperCase)

        // Find next lowercase character
        searchRange = upperCaseRange.lowerBound..<searchRange.upperBound
        guard let lowerCaseRange = stringKey.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters, options: [], range: searchRange) else {
            // There are no more lower case letters. Just end here.
            wordStart = searchRange.lowerBound
            break
        }

        // Is the next lowercase letter more than 1 after the uppercase? If so, we encountered a group of uppercase letters that we should treat as its own word
        let nextCharacterAfterCapital = stringKey.index(after: upperCaseRange.lowerBound)
        if lowerCaseRange.lowerBound == nextCharacterAfterCapital {
            // The next character after capital is a lower case character and therefore not a word boundary.
            // Continue searching for the next upper case for the boundary.
            wordStart = upperCaseRange.lowerBound
        } else {
            // There was a range of >1 capital letters. Turn those into a word, stopping at the capital before the lower case character.
            let beforeLowerIndex = stringKey.index(before: lowerCaseRange.lowerBound)
            words.append(upperCaseRange.lowerBound..<beforeLowerIndex)

            // Next word starts at the capital before the lowercase we just found
            wordStart = beforeLowerIndex
        }
        searchRange = lowerCaseRange.upperBound..<searchRange.upperBound
    }
    words.append(wordStart..<searchRange.upperBound)
    let result = words.map({ (range) in
        return stringKey[range].lowercased()
    }).joined(separator: "_")
    return result.uppercased()
}

enum Snake: String, UpperSnakeCaseRepresentable, Encodable {
    case blackAdder
    case mamba
}

struct Test: Encodable {
    let testKey: String?
    let snake: Snake
}
let test = Test(testKey: "testValue", snake: .mamba)

let enumData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(test)
let json = String(data: enumData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(json)
```

Comment: It looks like you need the values to be snake case, not the keys?

Comment: Yeah, I had my nomenclature mixed up. @rudedog provided some guidance, and I did get a working solution. I’ve added my code at the bottom of my original question, if you’re interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are actually looking for a value encoding strategy? A key encoding strategy changes how *keys* are encoded, not how their values are encoded. A value encoding strategy would be something like `JSONDecoder`'s `dateDecodingStrategy`, and you're looking for one for enums.

This is an approach that might work for you:

```
protocol UpperSnakeCaseRepresentable {
  var upperSnakeCaseValue: String { get }
}

extension UpperSnakeCaseRepresentable where Self: RawRepresentable, RawValue == String {
  var upperSnakeCaseValue: String {
    // Correct implementation left as an exercise
    return rawValue.uppercased()
  }
}

extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
  mutating func encode(_ value: UpperSnakeCaseRepresentable, forKey key: KeyedEncodingContainer<K>.Key) throws {
    try encode(value.upperSnakeCaseValue, forKey: key)
  }
}

enum Snake: String, UpperSnakeCaseRepresentable, Encodable {
  case blackAdder
  case mamba
}

struct Test: Encodable {
  let snake: Snake
}
let test = Test(snake: .blackAdder)

let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(test)
let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
print(json)
```

Now, any enums that you declare as conforming to `UpperSnakeCaseRepresentable` will be encoded as you want.

You can extend the other encoding and decoding containers the same way.

Comment: Fantastic! You're right, I am actually talking about the encoding of the value. The information and example you provide got me to a working implementation. Thanks!